Ignore a file when running `dnf update`
OS is RHEL9. I would like to configure dnf.conf to ignore a particular path when applying updates. Basically the equivalent to pacman.conf's NoUpgrade option (see pacman manual). Is there such an option?
My specific reason for wanting this is that on my virtualisation host I symlinked /var/lib/libvirt/images to /mnt/my-other-volume and placed the VM images there. But the libvirt-daemon-common package owns /var/lib/libvirt/images directory, which means dnf overwrites the symlink with a directory every time this package is updated, making the VMs unable to boot. I'm aware that I can configure libvirt to just use an alternate directory instead, but that's more work so I'd like to try the easier way first.
The closest option I could find in dnf.conf was excludepkgs, but that's not the same thing obviously.

If you are concerned with more work, then it would be less work to just have it use a different directory.
